# c# "For" keep getting 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Tags: c#

got datagridview with 3 data, I want to get the first cells data on each rows, when I use this kind of code

```
string[] DataGridViewArray = { };
            for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewArray[i] = DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
            }
            textBox1.Text = DataGridViewArray.ToString();
```

why it keep said 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: Because literally any value of `i` is outside the bounds of the array. The error is correct, as expected.

Comment: how big is `DataGridViewArray`?

Comment: Before you switch to a `List<string>`, without looping the Rows, check what `DataGridViewArray.ToString()` is going to return (try out, e.g., `string.Join()` after).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array is fixed size and its size is determined when declaring it (eg. in your first line of code) .

However, you gave it no single element nor set its size with expected number of items its going to hold - which in your case should be **DataGridView1.Rows.Count**.

```
       string[] DataGridViewArray = { };
```

Instead, if you replace that (line #1 code) as follows, it should work:

```
        string[] DataGridViewArray = new string[DataGridView1.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
             DataGridViewArray[i] = 
             DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Trim();
        }

        textBox1.Text = DataGridViewArray.ToString();
```

I don't have ***DataGridView1*** but I did something similar just to show you the reason why you are getting out of index error and how to fix it.

Clostly look at the length of the array in a way you defined it vs when array length is provided when declaring it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't properly instantiate your array so any iteration will be out of bounds.